# Pub/Sub How to notify users logged in a subscriber application?

Tags: web-applications, ejb, soa, publish-subscribe

I know the pattern pub/sub in theory and now I would like to implement it in practice.

I have a web application (subscriber) that contains a service that is listening for a channel called "news". This channel is populated by a list of other applications (publishers).

So, I would like to know, how to notify the logged user about the news received in real-time. (something like twitter "new twitts" does).

What I think:

in my consumer service I can store the news received in a List, something like:

```
@Consumer("myChannel")
public void recNews(New new) {
    allNews.add(new);
}
```

And then, configure a timer in my application to read and reset that List and send the current status (lastNews) to my web-controller:

```
@Timer("1 per minute")
public void lastNews() {
    lastNews.add(allNews);
    allNews = new ArrayList();
}
```

Am I right? Or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking to build a custom solution I would look at SignalR (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki). It handles a lot of the plumbing and infrastructure concerns for you and is ideal for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

The subscriber tells the publisher (channel) that it wants to receive the messages, before trying to receive.  The Channel is not some passive flow, it is an active process.

Use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/publish-subscribe-channel.html).

Or looking into [IP Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast).